# jQuery how read event submit from a form created in an iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, iframe

I have an issue; I trying to create a generic method to show a dialog interface in a WebPage, this dialog interface will contain an iFrame (To call any external WebPage - ASPX). The WebPage loaded in the iFrame will contain a form.

My intention is read the event "submit" of the form created in the iFrame from the main web page.

Basically, I have this method in the main WebPage:

```
$('#' + dialogId).contents().find('iframe').load(function (element) {
    $(element.currentTarget.contentDocument).find("form").on("submit", function (e) {
        alert('Form!!')
    });
});
```

I already have a `dialogId` (DIV element overpose in all the page, the iFrame is inside)

Comment: $(docuemnt).append("<iframe src='msgbox.asp'></iframe>")

Comment: can you share a codepen to demonstrate your case?